# How to invoke the lambda behind an API Gateway authorizer

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, authorization

I have the following CloudFormation stack. 2 lambdas (Greeting and Auth) with API Gateway configured to use the Auth lambda for authorisation.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  GreetingsApiGateway:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: MyAuthorizer
        Authorizers:
          MyAuthorizer:
            FunctionArn: !GetAtt AuthLambda.Arn

  GreetingsLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: "s3://<bucket-name>/code.zip"
      Handler: src/index.greeting
      Events:
        GetRoot:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref GreetingsApiGateway
            Path: /hello
            Method: get

  AuthLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: "s3://<bucket-name>/code.zip"
      Handler: src/index.auth

Globals:
  Function:
    Runtime: nodejs8.10
  # check whether I can use resources within globals

Outputs:
  ApiURL:
    Description: "OUR API URL"
    Value: !Sub "https://${GreetingsApiGateway}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
```

The code for my lambdas is as follows:

```
exports.greeting = async () => ({ statusCode: 200, body: "Hello Beautiful World!" });

exports.auth = async () => ({ statusCode: 200, body: "I wanna do the authorisation!" });
```

I expected the authorisation to fail all the time, but also to see the logs from the Auth lambda within my CloudWatch logs.

**What is happening:**

**Invoked from within the API Gateway**

If I hit the test without any headers from within the API Gateway console I get the "Hello Beautiful World" result. There are no lambda auth logs within my CloudWatch templates.

**Invoked from POSTMAN**

I tried sending this input within the headers of a GET request. The response was 'unauthorized' without any logs from within the Auth lambda CloudWatch logs.

```
{
    "type":"TOKEN",
    "authorizationToken":"<caller-supplied-token>",
    "methodArn":"arn:aws:execute-api:<regionId>:<accountId>:<apiId>/<stage>/<method>/<resourcePath>"
}
```

What is happening?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To retrieve the response we need to use the Authorization header, still do not understand why the request from API Gateway console retrieved a response.